# get a list of attributes from an element

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Still learning LINQ to XML and I'm having trouble parsing the data I want out.

The XML looks like this:

```
<address address1="5750 Ramirez Canyon Road" city="Malibu" state="CA" otherstate=" " postalcode="90265" country="US">
```

I want to create a dictionary of all the attributes. I have been trying various things and I'm just confusing myself. I keep getting null reference exception errors etc. I've been trying stuff like this:

```
var address = docCustomer
            .Element("address")
            .Attributes()
            .ToDictionary(....)
```

but obviously I'm doing something wrong because everything I try just bugs out.

Comment: Can you add the code where `docCustomer` is initialized/set? Can you post valid xml that reproduces the issue as well?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us the structure of your xml file.`docCustomer` refers to your xml document, if you want to get child elements of your `Root` use:

```
 docCustomer
 .Root.Element("address")
 .Attributes()
 .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => (string)x);
```

If `address` is not the direct element of your root this wouldn't work.Use `Descendants` if that is the case:

```
docCustomer
 .Descendants("address")
 .First()
 .Attributes()
 .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => (string)x);
```

Comment: `ToDictionary` doesn't allow duplicate keys. OP should probably clarify her/his intents a bit better.